# あの二人{ふたり}はどうもできているらしい's "できている"

Tags: grammar, slang

I came across a sentence lately that said あの二人はどうもできているらしい。"They seem to be in love with each other".

I'm having trouble understanding this usage because I couldn't find anything on it online.

できている would mean in love in that sentence but how does that work?

Answer (score 3):

できている has a slangy meaning "to be in a relationship / dating (secretly)".

明鏡国語辞典 says:

> できる
>   ❹《「できている」の形で》〔俗〕男女がひそかに結ばれたり言い交わしたりして、特別の関係になっている意を表す。「あの二人はできている」

Comment: Ah never realized my comment never went through a long time ago. Thanks and sorry about that, a more thorough look in the dictionary would have answered my own question~